# Laravel keeps giving error passwords.token

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, passwords, restore

The laravel 10 app is intended to be called by an SPA.
So it exposes these endpoints:

```
Route::post('/auth/forgot-password', [App\Http\Controllers\Api\AuthController::class, 'forgotPassword']);
Route::get('/reset-password/{token}', [App\Http\Controllers\Api\AuthController::class, 'getResetPassword'])->name('password.reset');
Route::post('/reset-password', [App\Http\Controllers\Api\AuthController::class, 'postResetPassword'])->name('password.update');
```

When SPA sends request to reset password

```
curl -d "email=nativeapp@example.com" -X POST http://localhost:9001/api/auth/forgot-password
```

this function is triggered:

```
public function forgotPassword(Request $request){
    $validateUser = Validator::make($request->all(),['email' => 'required|email']);
    if($validateUser->fails()){
        return response()->json([
            'status' => false,
            'message' => 'validation error',
            'errors' => $validateUser->errors()
        ], 401);
    }
    $status = Password::sendResetLink($request->only('email'));
    return response()->json(['status' => $status,], 200);
}
```

Upon that request, a new entry appears inside "password_reset_tokens":

```
 nativeapp@example.com
 $2y$12$jWSzTevYdNnVK/Rs8C1bfu/DCKWVvb4rL5VuMNPn41C.BkYwVIYvK
```

Side note for this GET endpoint that only verifies the token exists:

```
public function getResetPassword(Request $request){
    $result = DB::table('password_reset_tokens')->where(['token' => $request->token ])->exists();
    if(!$result){
        return response()->json(['status' => false, 'error' => 'no_such_token'], 500);
    }
    return response()->json(['status' => true], 200);
}
```

The POSt endpoint that received all the parameters looks like this:

```
public function postResetPassword(Request $request){
    $validateRequest = Validator::make($request->all(),['email' => 'required|email','token' => 'required','password' => 'required|min:8|confirmed']);
    if($validateRequest->fails()){
        return response()->json([
            'status' => false,
            'message' => 'validation error',
            'errors' => $validateRequest->errors()
        ], 401);
    }
    $status = Password::reset(
        $request->only('email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'),
        function (User $user, string $password) {
            $user->forceFill([
                'password' => Hash::make($password)
            ])->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));
            $user->save();
            event(new PasswordReset($user));
        }
    );
    if($status === Password::PASSWORD_RESET){
        return response()->json(['status' => true], 200);
    }
    else{
        return response()->json([
            'status' => false,
            'message' => 'validation error_in_else',
            'token' => $request->token,
            'errors' => $status
        ], 401);
    }
}
```

And is called this way:

```
http://localhost:9001/api/reset-password?email=nativeapp@example.com&token=$2y$12$jWSzTevYdNnVK/Rs8C1bfu/DCKWVvb4rL5VuMNPn41C.BkYwVIYvK&password=newpassword&password_confirmation=newpassword
```

In postman I always get this error:

```
{
"status": false,
"message": "validation error_in_else",
"token": "$2y$12$jWSzTevYdNnVK/Rs8C1bfu/DCKWVvb4rL5VuMNPn41C.BkYwVIYvK",
"errors": "passwords.token"
}
```

Why is this failing? Could be that it requires something else? A csrf token or something like that?

Tried to emulate code from tutorials which basically should work.

Comment: The tokens are hashed when they're sent to the user, they won't start with `$2y`. I'm not sure if it's hashed with `Hash::make`, but you can try that. Check the DatabaseTokenRepository.php to see how it's creating and checking the token.

Comment: Your `postResetPassword` route can be accessed through `post` method so why are you passing on query string?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your Passwort reset token is expired. You can change this in

config/auth.php

```
'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60, // Minutes
    ],
],
```